# Why does `mrt test-packages ./ ` fails when `meteor test-packages ./` does not

Tags: meteor, meteorite

`mrt test-packages ./` fails for my [dummy package](https://github.com/marcandre/meteor-dummy) but if I copy that package to meteor (renaming it's enclosing folder without the meteor- prefix), `meteor test-packages ./` succeeds.

It looks like it's due to using `_transitional_registerBuildPlugin`, because for other meteorite packages there is no such problem.

Is this a meteorite bug? a meteor bug? something else I'm missing?

My (extremely minimal) package: https://github.com/marcandre/meteor-dummy

Here's the backtrace I get:

```
$ mrt --version
Meteorite version 0.6.16
Release 0.6.6.3

$ mrt test-packages ./
(...)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at /Users/mal/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/tools/packages.js:703:28
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/mal/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:87:22)
    at /Users/mal/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/tools/packages.js:698:9
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/mal/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at _.extend._allHandlers (/Users/mal/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/tools/packages.js:697:7)
    at _.extend._getSourceHandler (/Users/mal/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/tools/packages.js:729:25)
    at /Users/mal/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/tools/packages.js:240:50
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/mal/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at _.extend.build (/Users/mal/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/tools/packages.js:235:7)
    at /Users/mal/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/tools/packages.js:1041:13
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/mal/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at _.extend.build (/Users/mal/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/tools/packages.js:1040:7)
    at /Users/mal/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/tools/library.js:251:15
    at Object.enterJob (/Users/mal/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/tools/buildmessage.js:219:15)
    at _.extend.get (/Users/mal/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/tools/library.js:236:22)
    at /Users/mal/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/tools/bundler.js:492:54
    at Array.map (native)
    at Function._.map._.collect (/Users/mal/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:97:56)
    at _.extend._determineLoadOrder (/Users/mal/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/tools/bundler.js:491:11)
    at _.extend.make (/Users/mal/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/tools/bundler.js:440:10)
    at makeClientTarget (/Users/mal/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/tools/bundler.js:1558:14)
    at /Users/mal/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/tools/bundler.js:1615:20
    at Object.capture (/Users/mal/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/tools/buildmessage.js:175:5)
    at Object.exports.bundle (/Users/mal/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/tools/bundler.js:1546:31)
    at /Users/mal/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/tools/run.js:509:32
    at /Users/mal/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/tools/fiber-helpers.js:24:12
```

```

Comment: Just use `meteor`, unless you're adding/removing packages from Atmosphere. Atmosphere and Meteorite are going to be rolled into the Meteor core for 1.0 anyway